# Remove Buttons Parent Container in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I guess this is a very basic question, but I have not been able to figure out the proper way to use "remove".

I want to use Jquery to make a button which deletes its parent container. Here is my Fiddle and Code.

As of now nothing happens, I havent even been getting a console error.

I have tried other methods (instead of "parents") including closest, with similar outcomes.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whyEnBe/t375qrwL/2/)

```
  <div class="delete_me">
<h3>Delete Me</h3>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DELETE ME">
</div>
<button name="button" onclick="removeThis();" type="button">Delete everything in my parent div</button>
```

```
function removeThis(){
    $(this).parents('.delete_me').remove();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t375qrwL/6/)**.

I guess that you can't add an `id` or an `class` so you have to pass the the object clicked to the function, example :

**HTML :**

```
<button name="button" onclick="removeThis(this);" type="button">Delete everything in my parent div</button>
```

**JS :**

```
function removeThis(_this){
    $(_this).parents('.delete_me').remove();
};
```

**NOTE :** If you can add `id` or `class` use solution in the other answers because Inline Event Handlers are really not recommended.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Yup I needed to pass in the object.

Comment: @WhyEnBe - in your fiddle you have your javascript block in an `onLoad()` handler (drop down in left column). For this to work using an inline `onclick="..."` you will need to change it to `no wrap - in <head>`. @Zakaria made that change to the fiddle in his updated link.

Answer (score 3):

Here man: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/t375qrwL/4/

```
<div class="delete_me">
    <h3>Delete Me</h3>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="DELETE ME">
    </div>
    <button name="button" type="button">Delete everything in my parent div</button>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why this wasnt working in on my actual site.

Comment: because you attached the event within your HTML tag. the This keyword gets bounded to de window object instead. I made an example for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/t375qrwL/7/ open your console and click on the buttons. if you want to attach your events via HTML you can always pass the this keyword as an argument. I hope this helps man

Comment: Thanks I am going to take a look at this.

Answer (score 3):

When using your code with the inline listener, your scope of `this` becomes the `window`. You should avoid adding event listeners inline anyways, so try it like this:

```
$('.delete_me button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.delete_me').remove();
});
```

Comment: Also note, that you can just use the following: ```$('.delete_me').remove();```

Comment: @MichaelStramel There may be multiple buttons like this on the page.

Comment: I am not sure why, but this solution doesnt seem to be working properly on my site, can you think of any reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your function is not working is that your `this` keyword is not scoped to the button*. In your function `this` refers to the `window` instead of the button being clicked. If you set up your function as a JQuery `.on('click', function(){...})` event, `this` will be properly scoped to the button that was clicked:

HTML:

```
<div class="delete_me">
  <h3>Delete Me!</h3>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DELETE ME">
  </div>
  <button id="removeBtn">Delete everything in my parent div</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#removeBtn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents('.delete_me').remove();
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/t375qrwL/3/)

* *in addition to the fact that you declare the function in an on-load handler so it goes out of scope once the on-load handler finishes*

Comment: Thanks, I couldnt pass in with an id though, not sure why it didnt work on my actual problem.